# Bootstrap: Columns over rows.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rows

I am using Bootstrap for a website. 
I have three rows in it that contain different things. 
In the second row down, I have some content to the right. 
The problem is that the content on the right is so tall that is pushed the 3rd row(the one below it) down as it gets bigger. 
So as it gains height, it pushes the third row down the page. 
Is their anyway to make it so that the content I put in one row, could go over another row?

Comment: Do you not want the second row to grow or do you just want rows to be able to overlap?

Comment: Please post your code, or better yet make a jsfiddle.